# Is there any other point of access modifiers other than better readibility?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I mean, if I declare any access modifier in Java, that modifier can be circumvented (package-private and protected - package injection; any - reflection). I know that declaring this stuff helps to understand and organize the code, but besides that, are there any technological reasons or inherent Java functionality?

Thank you guys for wonderful response. I only regret I can tag only one answer as accepted.

Comment: That is like saying: Why do we need a firewall. It can be circumvented. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I had a misleading title

Comment: @juergen Well if the purpose of access modifiers is protection, they do a very poor job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they can be circumvented.  The example of dependency injection which you pointed out is actually a useful case of circumvention.  Injection to private members doesn't pollute interfaces and isn't easy to muddle with at run-time. However to see the core benefit, think of it like you're a software architect presiding over a very lazy or inexperienced team.

Remember that well-factored objects should have high cohesion, and loose coupling.  High cohesion means that an object deals with the concerns it's semantically meant to deal with, nothing more, nothing less.  Loose coupling means that objects depend on interfaces rather than specific implementations.  Remember that the benefit to doing this is that it makes your code much easier to read, understand, test, and change.  This reduces cost and in general makes stakeholders happy.  As an architect, this is what you care about.  The hypothetical lazy/inexperienced team in question only cares about immediately finishing whatever tasks are in their queue, even at the expense of quality and future productivity.

Access modifiers show some of the intent behind the interface defined for an object.  Generally if you're writing well-factored code, you almost always only have need for public and private modifiers.  In the rare case where a concern can't be easily/clearly separated into a single cohesive object, there's also the "protected" keyword which allows limited external access from objects which should logically share the concern in question.

A better, though arguably more cumbersome, way of expressing the intent behind an interface is [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), which uses a much more robust set of interface annotations in order to allow preprocessing tools to enforce interface rules.

## tl;dr:

Compiler enforcement of access modifiers is wonderful.  The compiler puts up a pretty good barrier of inconvenience to those who would otherwise be happy reducing the cohesion and increasing the coupling of your codebase in order to cross off their immediate task quicker.

Comment: As an aside, if you're *really* interested in keeping an eye on the health of a codebase in which you might not read every line, static analysis tools like Sonar are a lifesaver -- especially when they're wired into SCM through hooks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, in that they prevent inadvertent misuse.  You *really* have to go out of your way to get round restrictions, you can't blindy do so.

Plus they signal an internal vs external/API intention. If you disregard that, as a user, then you acknowledge that you open yourself up to future problems.

Answer (score 2):

One massive reason (and the most important I believe) is that it gives you a better ability to reason about your code.

As an author of a class you have to make the assumption that your access modifiers will not be bypassed.  This allows you to make better assumptions about the state of your object before methods are called.  You *know* precisely where `private` methods will be called from and in what state the object is in.  You can't make the same assumptions about `public` methods.

An example might be that a `private` method may access some shared state in a multi-threaded context with the knowledge that it has been called from another method that holds a lock on the shared state, whereas the `public` methods may need to acquire the lock before accessing the shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

> that modifier can be circumvented (package-private and protected - package injection; any - reflection).

If you run with a security manager and signed JARs, neither of these is possible. So access modifiers can in fact be used as a security mechanism in controlled environments.

However, in the vast majority of cases, their purpose is indeed code organization (I don't think readability is the right word).

Answer (score 1):

As a different answer, I think they're important when writing an API as they define the public contract you're making with consumers of your API. You can get around them, yes, but it makes clear as to what is actually supported.

Answer (score 0):

Private/protected help make code safer and prevents tight coupling, which in turn facilitates reuse, reduces maintenance costs. I could go on all day!